# Adding anchor tags/onclick events to the css pseudo elements

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to add `onclick` event to the `:after`, and `:before` or simply add anchor tag inside it (or wrap it in it)? If yes, how can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

No, it isn't.

They don't exist in the DOM, so can't be targeted with JavaScript and cannot contain elements.